# How do I solve error in ExecuteReader();?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, visual-studio, oop

I am facing an issue with `ExecuteReader()`. When I am writing `MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`, I have a red line under `cmd.ExecuteReader()`. I am using Windows Form Application to read database from Microsoft SQL Server and using C# and OOP.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            con.Open();
            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                string q = "SELECT * from BuildingA30 where CONVERT(VARCHAR, FlatNo) = N'" + a11 + "' ";
                Console.WriteLine("Read all");
                Console.WriteLine(q);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    textBox1.Text = reader.GetString("tenantname");
                    textBox2.Text = reader.GetString("FlatNo");
                }
                textBox1.Text = q.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection success");
            }
```

Comment: Can you please add the error?

Comment: It seems you may be using be using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` (Microsoft SQL Server) which returns a `SqlDataReader` rather than a `MySqlDataReader` (for MySQL). The Intellisense error is probably indicating that.

Comment: You say SQL Server in your question, but you also tagged MySQL (which is a different product) - which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that SqlCommand.ExecuteReader returns a SqlDataReader, not a MySqlDataReader.

Here:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You're mixing ADO.NET providers.  Either use the SQL Server provider classes (if the database is SQL Server), or the MySql ones if it's MySql.  Not both.

Answer (score 0):

You install Dapper, then you don't have to waste your life writing boring, menial data reader code..

With Dapper that entire code you've written (yep all of it) would become something like `

```
using(var con = new MySqlConnection(...)){
    var rental = con.Query<RentalInfo>(
      "SELECT * FROM BuildingA30 WHERE flatNo = @f",
      new { f = all }
    };

    //use your rental object
```

This code is massively improved over the one you have there because:

- it's simple, quick to write, easy to read and debug
- it uses parameters and doesn't suffer from sql injection hacking risks - yours does
- it is strongly typed and can be async (note, mysql hasn't implemented async for their db provider, apparently but using async is a good habit to get into) - you just need to create a class called RentalInfo and add the relevant names properties to it;
- it doesn't call functions on the left hand side of an operator in the WHERE clause. Always a bad idea; don't call functions on millions of rows, call functions on constants and leave table data alone

http://dapper-tutorial.net

Note: I have no affiliation to Dapper or the guys who maintain that tutorial site